# TICoreDataSync - Compile issues, missing libTICoreDataSync.a

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, compiler-construction

I have checked out and compiled the icloud branch, added all the appropriate delegate methods to me app. But whenever i try to build the project i get the following error:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/garethjeanne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twitter_Translator-dhtkltxgqksalpcmkahykmmchszt/Build/Products/Debug/libTICoreDataSync.a'

When i look within the TICoreDataSync.xcodeproj i can see that the file is not built and is showing in red.

I've obviously missed something, thought the instructions seem a little out of date.

Help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Looks like it's trying to find a file that doesn't exist at that path.  You know for sure that file exists at that location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the source from github, now resolved.

Comment: Where did you find the file? I have looked all over github and can't seem to locate it.. Was that the only file missing or did you come across others as well?